# npm install openssl failed on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, openssl, npm-install

I am running the following command in Node.js command window in Win10. It failed. anyone has ideas how to fix it? I am running Node.js v7.3.0

```
C:\Users\haozhang>npm install openssl
C:\Users\haozhang
`-- openssl@1.1.0
  +-- mout@0.11.1
  `-- nyks@2.31.3
    +-- async@2.1.5
    | `-- lodash@4.17.4
    `-- mout@1.0.0

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\haozhang\package.json'
npm WARN haozhang No description
npm WARN haozhang No repository field.
npm WARN haozhang No README data
npm WARN haozhang No license field.

C:\Users\haozhang>openssl
'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: please align your question commands and separate it from result you get

Answer (score 19):

As mentionned by Royi Mindel the npm openssl package is just a wrapper around the openssl binaries and not the actual openssl. You need to install openssl on your Windows 10 machine as follows:

1. Download the binaries from https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads
2. Extract to `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\` (or whatever name you want to give it).
3. Add the system environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF` with value `c:\OpenSSL-Win32\openssl.cnf` (points to the config file where you extrated the binaries)
4. Add `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin` to your `Path` environment variable
5. Open a cmd or PowerShell and type `openssl version`. It should work and you should see the version installed

Info taken from: https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/openssl-windows.html

Comment: For anyone reading this: Don't download OpenSSL from the link provided above. The binaries are very old and have known security vulnerabilities. Here's a better option: https://www.openssl.org/community/binaries.html

Comment: thx @MikeDaly but I didn't see any directly downloadable stuff in your link. I got mine from here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the commands you are running, it seems like you are trying to use the installed npm module as an external command. You can achieve this only by installing the module globally:

```
npm install -g openssl
```

The warnings you get are expected. Each time you install a module **locally**, npm will try to update *your* `package.json` with the dependency to the module. Since you probably don't have a package.json in your home directory, you get the warning.

Comment: I edited my answer. Not sure what the downvotes were about, it just shows that people randomly click buttons instead of carefully reading the question.

Comment: I am guessing other people encountered the same issue - npm openssl package is just a wrapper to openssl binaries and not the actual openssl...I am looking for openssl binaries for an hour now. You did answer the op question tho.

Comment: true...it's a bit tricky to get it running on Windows. Ideally you would need to compile it from source, but that's no easy task either.

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads and setting Path and OPENSSL_CONF in environmental variables did the trick

Answer (score 0):

**1.Download OpenSSL**: Visit https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html to download OpenSSL for Windows.

**2. Add to PATH Environment Variable:**

After installing OpenSSL, locate the directory where it is installed, such as **C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin.**
Add this directory to your system's PATH environment variable:
Right-click on "This PC" or "My Computer" and select "Properties".
Go to "Advanced system settings" (or "System Properties" > "Advanced").
Click on the "Environment Variables" button.
In the "System variables" section, find the "Path" variable and select "Edit".
Add the directory containing OpenSSL (e.g., C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin) to the list of paths.
Click "OK" to save your changes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).