# Cannot run OpenSSL after installed by NPM on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: node.js, openssl, windows-10, npm-install

These are the steps I take to install openssl (or any package) and cannot run the installed package afterwards. Does anyone know why the package does not get added to node_path/Path ?

```
C:\>npm -v
6.13.0

C:\>npm install openssl -g
+ openssl@1.1.0
updated 1 package in 0.523s

C:\>openssl
'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have this in the Path:

```
C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules;
```

as well as Node_Path:

```
NODE_PATH=C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules;C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\openssl;
```

Comment: openSSL is not a program. What would you expect it to do when it ran? Perhaps a search for *what is openssl* in your favorite search engine would help.

Comment: it is node package and should run when called. The folder with complete content is created in ..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules (installation has been successful) but somehow npm cannot set up the command prompt (the environment) to call it from anywhere I want to run openssl.

Comment: It is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918916/npm-install-openssl-failed-on-windows-10

Comment: Being a module does not mean it's directly executable on its own. OpenSSL libraries exist for things other than node (eg., as DLLs for Windows and .so libraries for *nix); they contain functionality that is called from your application code to provide secure socket support, but you can't run the OpenSSL library directly from a command prompt. I'm still not sure you understand what OpenSSL is and what it's for, I'm afraid. OpenSSL are libraries that provide secure socket communications - it's not a standalone program.